# Having problems in the store method Laravel-Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Been at this for a very long time and I can't get it right. Would be really thankful for some help. Thanks in advance! 
Im trying to build a little clone of reddit some learning purpose.

I think these models is correct for what I'm trying to do. Im able to save a Subreddit to DB with user_id. But my problem is that I can't post to the post table since it's telling me it cannot find the subreddits_id column. Im seems like the method im trying to call should be working but it doesnt.

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'link','content', 'post_picture', 'user_id', 'subreddit_id'];


//Functions

public function user () {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function subreddit() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Subreddit::class);
}

public function comments () {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Above is my Post model

```
protected $guarded = [];

//Functions

public function user () {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function posts () {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function comments () {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Above is my Subreddit Model

```
public function posts () {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function subreddit() {
    return $this->hasMany(Subreddit::class);
}

public function commments () {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Above is my User model

I think these models is correct for what I'm trying to do. Im able to save a Subreddit to DB with user_id. But my problem is that I can't post to the post table since it's telling me it cannot find the subreddits_id column. Im seems like the method im trying to call should be working but it doesnt.

The Store method looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'link' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);


    $post = auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);
return redirect('/home');

}
```

I'm getting this error General error: 1364 Field 'subreddit_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `link`, `content`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (awe, ew, we, 2, 2020-04-01 17:41:29, 2020-04-01 17:41:29))

Answer (score 0):

your `$data` only takes the parameters you specify for validation, But you did not include `subreddit_id`,
 It should be like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ $data = request()->validate([
    'title' => 'required',
    'link' => 'required',
    'content' => 'required',
    'subreddit_id' => 'required|exist:subreddits,id'
]);


$post = auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);
return redirect('/home');

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not getting the error when posting now but nothing happens. It just refreshes the page and the text disapears

Comment: Is it adding the record to `posts` table?

Comment: No it doesn't unfortuantly

Comment: Then its one of the rule of validation, Try removing the `exist` rule if u don't have a `subreddit` record, And if it still doesn't work, Try  to `echo` the `$request `and `$data` see if its sending the right data for `create`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that also but it wont work. Very annoying. It is something with the subreddit_id but i cant figure it out